# How to use modal Bootstrap in angular ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table in Angular that gets list of names. I want to be able to delete a name when the user click on the button in front of the name. However, before that, I want to show a modal and ask the user to confirm that.

```html
  <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
        <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Name</th>
         </tr>
          </thead>
             <tbody>
             <tr data-ng-repeat="c in vm.entity | filter:vm.filter track by c.Id">
                 <td>
                     <span>{{c.Name}}</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>                                           
                     <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" type="button"   data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm"></button>

                   </td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
     </table>
```

I am using Bootstap modal and here is what I have.

```html
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you sure you want to delete this Item?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                <button type="button" data-ng-click="vm.remove(c)" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

The problem is since the buttons in the modal are not in the loop I can't pass in the correct object into the `vm.remove` method to delete the item.

Does anyone know how to deal with this issue?

Comment: Why don't put the modal div right after button? thenit has to be in scope

Comment: I have tried it but when I click on the button it opens a modal for each element in the list

Comment: check Angular bootstarp directives http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23036649/158421

Answer (score 3):

Ok Guys,

Thanks for all your help.

I have managed to fix it by moving the modal right next to the button so the modal is repeated as well as the button as @Dabbiemiller suggested and then I assign a ID for each modal that matches the id of each element, and I assign the data-target= "modal{{c.id}}" and it works :)

Also I have changed  to  becase the fade class was causing an issue as well.

```
<button class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ng-show="vm.isAdmin == 'True'" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal{{c.id}}"></button>
<div class="modal" id="modal{{c.id}}">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure?</h4>
          </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Are you sure you want to delete this Item?</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
              <button type="button" data-ng-click="vm.remove(c)" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
              </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
   </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

---